# C : using getchar() in double while loop - stuck in loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, getchar

Im using this double while loop. Im new to C.

```
int crawler;
char *desired[100];

crawler = getchar();

while(crawler != EOF) {

    int i = 0;

    while((crawler != '\n') && (crawler != EOF)) {
        desired[i] = crawler;
        i++;
        crawler = getchar();
    }

    printf("%s", desired);

}
```

I just dont see why Im getting infinite loop in here (LLLLLLLLL..). Stdin looks like this:

```
Lorem(newline)
Ipsum(newline)
Beach(newline)
Crocodile(newline)
Crox(newline)
C(EOF)
```

Any idea? thanks.

Comment: `char *desired[100];` -> `char desired[100];`. Also turn on compiler warnings  (`gcc -Wall ...`) and pay attention to them !

Comment: thanks, i missed that.

Comment: 1.) `printf("%s", desired);` <- you can't guarantee `desired` is a string here, it probably doesn't contain a terminating `\0` byte! 2.) your inner loop will happily overflow `desired`, add a check!

Comment: And don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-terminator* Is important to not forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer loop ends when `crawler` is `EOF`.

Your inner loop ends when `crawler` is `'\n'` or `EOF`.

Only the inner loop reads input (by calling `getchar`).

Therefore: As soon as the first `'\n'` is read, the inner loop is never re-entered (the condition rejects `'\n'`), but the outer loop doesn't end, and it never changes the value of `crawler`.

Result: The outer loop spins without reading any input.